# Multi Threading work properly But GUI Hang When new thread create in vb

Tags: vb.net, multithreading

I have a problem with this vb code. I have two buttons to create different counting threads. I am using invoke to update GUI label when I create a single thread it works fine but when I press button 2 to create a new thread then both labels are hang(new value is not update).
no exception, no error

```
Public Class Form1



Dim Thread1 As System.Threading.Thread
Dim Thread2 As System.Threading.Thread
Delegate Sub ThreadDelegateTemplate(ByVal str As String)

Public myThread1 As ThreadDelegateTemplate
Public myThread2 As ThreadDelegateTemplate

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

End Sub
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    myThread1 = New ThreadDelegateTemplate(AddressOf updateLabel)
    Thread1 = New System.Threading.Thread(AddressOf upcount)
    Thread1.Start()
End Sub
Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    myThread2 = New ThreadDelegateTemplate(AddressOf updateLabel2)
    Thread2 = New System.Threading.Thread(AddressOf upcount2)
    Thread2.Start()
End Sub
Private Sub upcount()
    Dim i As Integer = 0
    Do Until i = 10000
        i = i + 1
        Invoke(myThread1, New Object() {Convert.ToString(i)})
    Loop
End Sub
Private Sub updateLabel(ByVal str As String)
    Label1.Text = str
End Sub
Private Sub upcount2()
    Dim i2 As Integer = 0
    Do Until i2 = 10000
        i2 = i2 + 1
        Invoke(myThread2, New Object() {Convert.ToString(i2)})
    Loop
End Sub
Private Sub updateLabel2(ByVal str As String)
    Label2.Text = str
End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: This does not look like VBA code.

Comment: It could be because your two threads run without delay and both try to update the UI simultaneously. If the UI thread is too busy it won't have time to redraw. Try inserting `Label1.Refresh()` and `Label2.Refresh()` after changing the text in your two `updateLabel` methods.

Comment: Thank you, sir, for help but, if I am using multiple text box, chart, MySQL DB status and serial within different threads then can I use refresh method?

Comment: I don't know, it depends on many different factors. However if you find yourself updating the UI too often, then you might have to rethink your pattern.